# Multiply random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

To multiply and add two random variables, must they have the same domain (sample space)? Should you add and multiply the variables for each element of the sample space?
$$
X:  \Omega  \to \mathbb{R} \qquad \qquad  Y:\Omega  \to \mathbb{R} 
$$
$$XY=$$
$$f(x_1)g(y_1)$$
$$f(x_2)g(y_2)$$
$$...$$
$$f(x_n)g(g_n)$$

Comment: Similar question: If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ are functions defined by $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x)= \cos(x)$, does that mean $fg = \sin(0)\cos(0) \quad \sin(0.1)\cos(0.1) \quad \sin(0.2)\cos(0.2)...$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X,Y$ are both random variables on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ then $XY$ and $X+Y$ are also random variables on this same probability space.

That means that - just like $X$ and $Y$ - they are Borel-measurable functions $\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

They are prescribed by:$$\omega\mapsto X(\omega)Y(\omega)$$and:$$\omega\mapsto X(\omega)+Y(\omega)$$
If $X$ and $Y$ have different domains then these prescriptions do not make sense.